# How do I discover a PPA's PGP key?

Tags: 12.04, ppa, openpgp

I would like to be able to see the openPGP key of a PPA.  I do not wish to add it to my sysetm.  I only need to know what the key is.  How might I discover this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find that out by going to the PPA page.

I'm using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~sergio91pt/+archive/synaptics+clickpads) as an example.

Head to your PPA link, and then click "Technical details about this PPA".

[image]

What you're looking for is the "Signing key", in this case it's `1024R/D306B7D0`, which is also a link to the [Keyserver.ubuntu.com entry](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?search=0xC346647A6811E6DC5F58B789A58D590ED306B7D0&op=index) for the key.

You can then do whatever you need to do for that.

Comment: In fact, you may have helped me twice!  Maybe this PPA will get my clickpad going proper!

Comment: @DeanHowell Only works for 11.10, 12.04 doesn't work well with it.

Answer (score 4):

[As jrg said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177479/how-do-i-discover-a-ppas-pgp-key/177482#177482) you can go to the launchpad's page, but, if you don't want to open your browser, or, if you have too many ppas so as to do that manually, you can use this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$(mktemp)

wget -q "$1" -O $tmp
code=$(grep "<code>" $tmp | tr -d ' ')
code=${code:6:14}
echo $code
rm -f $tmp
```

Usage: [image: usage]